# Issues with installing TensorFlow/Python onto my Windows computer

Tags: python, windows, installation, tensorflow

Currently I am trying to follow the [Google Deep Learning Course](https://www.udacity.com/course/deep-learning--ud730), and am facing the issue of installing and running **TensorFlow** on my Windows PC.

[These](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-install-and-run-tensorflow-on-a-windows-pc/) are the instructions of how to install **TensorFlow** onto my computer. However these fail at this point:

```
docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

with the error shown below:

[image]

Now after looking at [this](https://caffinc.github.io/2015/11/tensorflow-windows/) article, and trying out the line `docker pull b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow`, I seem to get the same error:

[image]

Has anyone succesfully installed `Docker` and `TensorFlow` onto their computers? Thank you for your answers. Please do not hesitate to ask me about anything that would clarify this question.

Comment: You could build the docker image yourself, go inside tensorflow/tools/docker and do `docker build .`

Comment: @fabrizioM could you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Try my answer. If it doesn't work, try using Kitematic Software that comes bundled with Docker installation.

Comment: docker run -p 8888:8888 -it --rm b.gcr.io/tensorflow-udacity/assignments:0.5.0

from [Assignments for Udacity Deep Learning class with TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/README.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't have a running VM. The easiest way is to launch "Docker Quick Start Terminal". It will (create and) run a VM.

Since you want to do Udacity assignments, you can try the following command in the opened Docker Terminal:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v b.gcr.io/tensorflow-udacity/assignments:0.5.0
```

I personally use this command:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v /$(pwd)/tensorflow:/notebooks --memory=8g --name tf b.gcr.io/tensorflow-udacity/assignments:0.5.0
```

where:

- `--memory=8g` is to increase memory
- `--name tf` is to give the container a name
- `-v /$(pwd)/tensorflow:/notebooks` mounts a folder from host to the container. This folder MUST be inside your windows user folder. As you can see I created a folder named `tensorflow` inside my windows user folder and put all the assignment notebooks in there.

To access the Jupyter notebook on your browser go to "the Virtual Machine IP":8888 which is usually 192.168.99.100:8888.

If you named the container as I did, you can use `docker start tf` to start it next time.

Answer (score 1):

To build and run a CPU only tensorflow on a windows system that has docker installed you can

```
cd tensorflow/tools/docker
docker build -t tensorflow 
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow
```

That will give you a bash console with a built tensorflow

Comment: Does this onto the docker console or the windows cmd line?

Comment: Also, I don't even have tensorflow on my system - When I tried to get the files, look at what happened

Comment: As you can see, I get a ping timeout when trying to get those files